# Calling Oracle Stored Procedure from Laravel which has 2 IN and one OUT parameters

Tags: php, oracle, laravel, pdo, oci8

1. Here is my Procedure:

   create or replace PROCEDURE GET_CONTENT(IID IN INTEGER, key IN RAW, DATA 
      OUT CLOB)
      AS
      BEGIN
      SELECT ENCRYPT_DECRYPT.DECRYPT(DATA, KEY, UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(key)) 
      INTO DATA
      FROM AUDIT_TABLE 
      WHERE ID = IID;
      END;
2. Here is what i have been trying:

   ```
   $pdo = DB::connection('oracle')->getPdo();

   $sql = 'CALL GET_CONTENT(?,?,?)';
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $lid =  11;
   $key = 'MASTERKEY';
   $stmt->bindParam(1, $lid, PDO::PARAM_INT, 10);
   $stmt->bindParam(2, $master_key, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INT, 100);
   $stmt->bindParam(3, $DataResult, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 
   200);
   print "Values of bound parameters _before_ CALL:\n";
   print "  1: {$lid} 2: {$key}\n";

   $stmt->execute();

   print "Values of bound parameters _after_ CALL:\n";
   print "  1: {$lid} 2: {$key}\n";


   Error: Illegal name variable/number
   ```

Comment: Honest question - why use the `pdo` driver for an oracle database when you can use the `oci` driver?

Comment: Was trying with oci but had some issues there as well... Can you please help me with this or how do we call this procedure using oci driver.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I agree - use OCI8.  Also, try to debug your problem.  Your PHP script ran for me, but I didn't have your table so I used `create or replace PROCEDURE GET_CONTENT(IID IN INTEGER, key IN RAW, DATA OUT CLOB) AS BEGIN data := 'abc'; END;`